# Ink tools for Microsoft Access 2016 form, table grids

Tags: ms-access-2013, excel-2016, ms-access-2016, word-2016, microsoft-ink

I searched a lot for enabling Ink tools feature in Microsoft Access 2016. I wanted to use either the [Pen(digital pen)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Draw-and-write-with-ink-in-Office-6d76c674-7f4b-414d-b67f-b3ffef6ccf53) , though the Microsoft Ink tools for office is available for Word, Excel it is seems not for Microsoft Access forms, tables grid. Interesting is for Word 2016 you can use with mouse as well. There is one signature tool as well, that allows writing in mouse like hand written and converts to text.

[Windows Ink](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/windows-ink) seems to available for office apps , but not Microsoft Access 2016 forms.

I am searching whether or how we can use Ink Tools in Access 2016 forms, specially text box etc. I am using Windows 10 32 bit , Access 2016 32 bit.

Comment: I guess your only option is to include a Word object in your form.

Comment: but that will make the process of writing a much slower, if its available in MS Access for image control or text box... that would improve ease of doing and using ink feature in Access...

Comment: But - it is not.